# PHP: Trying to file_get_contents sibling folders locally in Windows 10 gives Permission Denied

Tags: php, windows, local

I am not in any server nor hosting locally.  Plain php on Windows 10, I can't print out the content of sibling folders.

eg. `file_get_contents("../SiblingFolder")` throws the error:

```
Failed to open stream: permission denied
```

I tried to icacls the C drive but that didn't do anything either.

I am the only user and thus automatically the admin of the computer.  [I have set myself as the owner of the PC.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coFh4.png)

How do I give permission to folders so that I can use file_get_contents() on them?

Comment: Q: "plain PHP" ... or are you executing your PHP through a web server?  IIS7?  XAMPP?  Other?  Q: Does fopen() (or any alternate file access) also give "permission denied"?  Q: What about absolute path (vs. relative path)?

Comment: "plain PHP" as in not ran through a web server.  Basically not on the internet at all.  fopen() gives the same error.  Absolute path also gives the same error.  Am I understanding PHP incorrectly?  Do PHP scripts not work without a server?

Comment: You're understanding PHP perfectly correctly.  It's a scripting language; it does *not* need a server.  There's *probably* some setting or another you can configure in php.ini to resolve the problem ... but frankly, I'm  out of ideas.  Sorry :(